# Angular Threejs Collada

Tags: angular, typescript, three.js

I hope you can help me. I have to realize a webapp with Angular4 with THREEjs to view Collada Objects, but I'm failing completely.

> UPDATE: I hope somebody can show me a working example or give me a hint. I already did alot of research in Google and looked for code with other loaders.

That's the typescript code for the related component.

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { GlobalVarService} from '../global-var.service';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {ColladaLoader} from 'three';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game',
  templateUrl: './game.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game.component.css'],
  providers: [ ]
})
/*

*/
export class GameComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('rendererContainer') rendererContainer: ElementRef;

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  scene = null;
  camera = null;
  mesh = null;
  clock=null;

  constructor() {


    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 2000 );
    this.camera.position.set( 8, 10, 8 );
    this.camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 3, 0 ) );
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.clock = new THREE.Clock();
    // loading manager
    var loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager( function() {
      this.scene.add( self );
    } );
    // collada
    var loader = new ColladaLoader( );//THREE.ColladaLoader() gives the same error
    /*loader.load( './models/collada/elf/elf.dae', function ( collada ) {
     // self = collada.scene;
    } );*/
    //
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.4 );
    this.scene.add( ambientLight );
    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
    directionalLight.position.set( 1, 1, 0 ).normalize();
    this.scene.add( directionalLight );
    //
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    //

    //
    //window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );




    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh();


    this.scene.add(this.mesh);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.renderer.setSize(600, 400);
      this.renderer.domElement.style.display = "block";
      this.renderer.domElement.style.margin = "auto";
      this.rendererContainer.nativeElement.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

      this.animate();
  }

  animate() {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate());
      this.mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
      this.mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;
      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }
}
```

While compiling I get this message

> WARNING in ./src/app/game/game.component.ts
>       44:25-38 "export 'ColladaLoader' was not found in 'three'
>       webpack: Compiled with warnings.

And when I open the Webapp:

> ERROR 
>           Error: [object Object]
>           Stack trace:
>           resolvePromise@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3198:31
>           resolvePromise@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3169:17
>           scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3246:17
>           ../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:4200 /polyfills.bundle.js:2839:17
>           onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111709:24
>           ../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2838:17
>           ../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2606:28
>           drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3010:25
>           core.es5.js:1020
>           ReferenceError: THREE is not defined

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `THREE.ColladaLoader` is not part of the library itself, and is in an `examples/js/loaders` folder. [Currently it's not possible to include it as an ES6 import](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9562), so you'll probably want to just copy the file into your project.

Comment: How can I do that?
I already tried to import the file via the package.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THREE.ColladaLoader is not part of the three.js library itself, and is in an `examples/js/loaders` folder. [Currently it's not possible to include these as ES6 imports](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9562). You'll need to quite literally copy [ColladaLoader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/0e44cfd0cdcdfb8f69887024690fcc048ac7d2c1/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js) into a new file, in your project, then add appropriate imports and exports to it:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

var ColladaLoader = function () { ... }

export ColladaLoader;
```

As an alternative, it is possible to use CommonJS imports if WebPack (I assume you're using WebPack?) is configured for CommonJS. Example:

```
const THREE = require('three');
require('three/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader');
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it and inform you whether it works

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, but I'm not sure whether your second code snippet is relevant or just an hint to another solution?
At the moment I didn't get it to work.

Comment: The second snippet is an alternative. Which to use would probably depend on how WebPack is configured.